# How to capture packets of VPN

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, openvpn, pptp

I hava 2 VPN servers, one is pptp, one is openVPN, I need to capture the VPN response packets for

the VPN client, and later I need to forward these packets to vpn clients by another linux server. I

want to know is it possible? if possible, how to capture these packages by libpcap ? what is the

filter ? thanks!

Comment: I'm not very clear on what you mean by "response packets" - do you mean with VPN encapsulation, or the payload inside?

Comment: I mean the VPN encapsulation which can be handled by VPN programe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use  command  ' ngrep'  in gateway.